# WordPress multisite under nginx partially working

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite

To set the scene, the below config is under a single domain name, used for development purposes, so we already have many single-instance WordPress sites running under sub directories.

I am now trying to configure a multisite instance under its own sub directory.

Example regular WordPress instance:

```
URL: http://example.com/path/one
Path: /srv/web/example.com/public/path/one
```

Example multisite WordPress instance:

```
URL: http://example.com/path/two
Path: /srv/web/example.com/public/path/two
```

The Multisite instance is not working as expected.

The root site at http://example.com/path/two works.

The wp-admin paths without a training '/' are rewriting correctly to wp-admin/ as expected, for both the parent and children sites.

The only 'child' site named 'site1' at http://example.com/path/two/site1/wp-admin/ shows a broken page and subsequent URLs under that path return 'file not found' by php-fpm.

I'm trying to avoid using `if (!-e $request_filename ) { ... }` syntax, as per many different multisite config examples on-line.

What have I missed in my config below? Pointers would be appreciated.

```
server {
   listen ...;
   ...
   index index.php;

   location /path/one {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /path/one/index.php?$args;
   }
   location /path/two {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress_multi;
   }
   location @wordpress_multi {
       rewrite wp-admin$ $request_uri/ permanent;
       rewrite ^/path/two/([^/]+/)?(wp-.*) /path/two/$2 last;
       rewrite ^/path/two/([^/]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /path/two/$2 last;
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /path/two/index.php?$args;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: In `^/path/two(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*)`, is the `?` wise, as it also matches the target which would probably lead to a redirection loop.

Comment: Thanks for the input @RichardSmith - the 'last' directive takes care of that it seems.

Comment: The third rewrite (for URIs ending with `.php`) is never executed, as the `location ~ \.php$` block is selected to process the request. Do you have a `try_files` statement in that block?

Comment: I was mistaken.

Official info on 'last' is here: 

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

last - "stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;"

I have yet to see any loops though. I will enable rewrite_log and trace what occurs:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log